# Receive the session in list Box in separate rows

Tags: c#, session

hello m using visual studio 2012 , and trying to send session on different web page. its transferring my sessions but the problem is it is not showing in separate rows :( m using this code

```
Session["ProductName" + "\n"] += "\n" + ProductName;  //this is on page 1

string pName = Convert.ToString(Session["ProductName" + "\n"]);
ListBox1.Items.Add("\n" + pName);      //this one m using on targeted page
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not showing in separate rows"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.NewLine` :

```
Session["ProductName" ] += Environment.NewLine + ProductName;  //this is on page 1
```

Then you will not have  to use `"/n"` in the other page Also.

Comment: now i m sending sessions from lables. and i have so many sessions from different web Form and want to display on one page named "Cart" and in only one list box respectivly. what should i do :(

Comment: @Ghori you want to display each session content in a listbox?